# 「許可が来ましたか？」の尊敬語

Tags: politeness, business-japanese

```
A社の社長
↑
A社のプロジェクトマネージャー
↑
私                                                       ↑：許可を依頼する
```

私は作業を始める前、お客さん（A社）の許可を待っています。

A社のプロジェクトマネージャーが先週「社長に許可を依頼する」と言ってましたが、期日が近づいてますのでどうなったかを知りたいです。

つまり、「許可が来ましたか？」をA社のプロジェクトマネージャーに聞きたいです。もちろん尊敬語などを使わないといけません。

周りへの影響が大きい作業なので、単純に「作業を始めてよろしいでしょうか」と聞くと「待って！社長の許可が必要と言ったよ」と思われそうです。そして、曖昧な言い方をせずに、少し積極的にA社の中で動いてるかどうかを聞きたい気持ちがあります。

「許可が来ましたでしょうか」はなんとなく違和感あります。「許可が参りましたか」も間違ってるだろうと思いますが、どう書けば良いですか？

Answer (score 4, accepted):

許可 ("permission") is an inanimate noun, so it's hard to use an honorific/humble verb if it's a subject. Both 許可がいらっしゃった and 許可が参った sound funny. If you need, it's fine to say まだ御社社長からの許可が来ていません without an honorific verb. You can also use ございます and say まだ御社社長からの許可がございません, すでに社長の許可はございますでしょうか, etc. Alternatively, 許可 is also a suru-verb, so you can say 御社社長は許可していただけましたでしょうか.

Answer (score 1):

A Japanese colleague just suggested me this, so I post it as an alternative:

> 許可の連絡は来ましたでしょうか？

I am a bit surprised that it is not `ご連絡`, but I guess there is some reason for that...